# Python sequential number generator with 0-9 and A-Z

Tags: python, generator

I'm trying to accomplish a number generator which increments numbers (0-9) and characters (A-Z not case-sensitive) for unique identification of some object in our software project.
The output string should have a length of 14.

The generator should be able to create a range of sequential numbers/characters (see examples below) which will be used on potential hundres of devices running some python applications with databases.
We would like to implement following logic and 'provide' these sequential number ranges to the devices so we make sure we have unique ids across all systems. We would prefer this logic instead of classic random id creation.

Increment should start from right to left. Numbers start with 0-9. If 9 is reached, the index should then increment from A-Z. If Z is reached, the left index number should be incremented from 0 to 1 or 9 => A-Z(one higher). The right index should then again be incremented by the same logic starting by 0 => 1-9 and afterwards A-Z.

A few example outputs:

- 00000000000009
- 0000000000000A
- 0000000000000B

Or:

- 0000000000000Z
- 00000000000010
- 00000000000011

And so on.

The function should also be able to start at a given number, for e.g. 00000000005X which then continues with 00000000005Y etc..

How can I build this in Python?

Comment: Please update your question with the code you have tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This program only uses the `string` module, and not `itertools`
I also added constants called `LENGTH` and `START` which you can change

Code:

```py
from string import ascii_uppercase

sequence = [str(i) for i in range(10)] + list(ascii_uppercase)

LENGTH = 14
START = '0' * LENGTH

last = list(START)
while last != list('Z' * LENGTH):
    print(''.join(last))
    i = 1
    while last[-i] == 'Z':
        last[-i] = '0'
        i += 1
    last = last[:-i] + [sequence[sequence.index(last[-i]) + 1]] + last[LENGTH-i+1:]
```

Output:

```html
00000000000000 
00000000000001 
00000000000002 
00000000000003 
00000000000004 
00000000000005 
00000000000006 
00000000000007 
00000000000008 
00000000000009 
0000000000000A 
0000000000000B 
0000000000000C 
0000000000000D 
0000000000000E 
0000000000000F 
0000000000000G 
0000000000000H 
0000000000000I 
0000000000000J 
0000000000000K 
0000000000000L 
0000000000000M 
0000000000000N 
0000000000000O 
0000000000000P 
0000000000000Q 
0000000000000R 
0000000000000S 
0000000000000T 
0000000000000U 
0000000000000V 
0000000000000W 
0000000000000X 
0000000000000Y 
0000000000000Z 
00000000000010 
00000000000011 
00000000000012 
00000000000013 
00000000000014 
00000000000015 
00000000000016 
00000000000017 
00000000000018 
00000000000019 
0000000000001A 
0000000000001B 
0000000000001C 
0000000000001D 
0000000000001E 
0000000000001F 
0000000000001G
...
```

Comment: In your last line, better just update `last[-i]`.

Comment: Pretty sure `while last != 'Z' * LENGTH:` will never finish, because `last` is always a list, and yet it's being compared to a string. The performance here will also be pretty horrendous as written. `last = last[:-i] + [sequence[sequence.index(last[-i]) + 1]] + last[LENGTH-i+1:]` Every loop replaces the current list by a new list formed by multiple list concatenations? This isn't written as a generator function, though it would have to be to answer the question. It also can't start at an arbitrary point (though that requirement seems to have been added later).

Comment: This works perfectly. I can now pass and override the START constant to start at specific position to integrate it into our project. Thank you very much (@BrokenBenchmark as well) for providing such quick help, im not that good at such stuff yet.

Comment: @Lovethenakedgun Oh yeah - forgot about that, should say `list('Z' * LENGTH)` - thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 2):

You can use constants from the `string` module to get all the digits / uppercase ASCII characters, and then use `itertools.product` to generate the IDs:

```py
import string
import itertools

# Create the iterable.
characters = string.digits + string.ascii_uppercase
n = 14
id_iterable = map(''.join, itertools.product(characters, repeat=n))

# Get the first 50 elements in the iterable and print them out (for demo purposes).
head = list(itertools.islice(id_iterable, 50))
print(*head, sep='\n')
```

This outputs:

```
00000000000000
00000000000001
00000000000002
00000000000003
00000000000004
00000000000005
00000000000006
00000000000007
00000000000008
00000000000009
0000000000000A
0000000000000B
0000000000000C
0000000000000D
0000000000000E
0000000000000F
0000000000000G
0000000000000H
0000000000000I
0000000000000J
0000000000000K
0000000000000L
0000000000000M
0000000000000N
0000000000000O
0000000000000P
0000000000000Q
0000000000000R
0000000000000S
0000000000000T
0000000000000U
0000000000000V
0000000000000W
0000000000000X
0000000000000Y
0000000000000Z
00000000000010
00000000000011
00000000000012
00000000000013
00000000000014
00000000000015
00000000000016
00000000000017
00000000000018
00000000000019
0000000000001A
0000000000001B
0000000000001C
0000000000001D
```

Comment: Thats perfect. I tried using a list of numbers and the string module before but struggled to do the increment on the proper index. How would I give this code the ability to take an input start value which works with the numer of elements it should return?

Comment: I'm not sure if I follow. What input do you want to take in?

Comment: I would like to give an input "00000000005X" and then start the generator at that point and let it continue from there on. This is crucial so we can "request" another range of numbers from the system and return it to the client if he runs out of numbers.

Comment: @Paze I have added a START constant in my answer - I think this is what you are after

Comment: You can use `itertools.islice()` with some base-36 math to figure out where to start the slice, but @TheThonnu's answer is probably more suited for this.

Comment: @Paze With over 6 sextillion numbers, you likely won't run out in your lifetime.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

```
import numpy as np

def f(start):
    n = int(start, base=36)
    while True:
        yield np.base_repr(n, 36).rjust(14,"0")
        n += 1
```

Then:

```
g = f('0000000000012S')

for i in range(10):
    print(next(g))
```

It gives:

```
0000000000012S
0000000000012T
0000000000012U
0000000000012V
0000000000012W
0000000000012X
0000000000012Y
0000000000012Z
00000000000130
00000000000131
```

Answer (score 0):

Was using your question as an exercise to see if I could quickly implement the algorithm in JS, wasn't intending on providing the solution, as I expected this "homework-style" question would get answers pretty quickly. @bb1's numpy solution seems quite good, as does the itertools approach (though it's not actually written as a generator function). Though both have library overheads.

Was a bit surprised there wasn't a good algorithmic approach, just library answers. So figured I'd share mine even though it was in the wrong language. Adopting this for Python shouldn't be too tricky, outside of *maybe* converting the JS closure to a generator function in Python. As this is written, if we happen to hit "ZZZZZZZZZZZZZZ" the next value generated is "00000000000000" and we restart.

```js
function GetGenerator(start_val) {
    
    const min_val = "0"
    const id_len = 14;
    
    if (start_val && start_val.length != id_len) 
        throw "Initial value length isn't " + id_len
    
    // A dictionary mapping each character to the next & 'Z' to 'undefined'
    const incrementer = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ".split("")
        .reduce((acc, cur, idx, arr) => (acc[cur] = arr[idx+1], acc), {})
    
    const counter = start_val ? start_val.split("") : Array(id_len).fill(min_val)
    
    function increment() {
        //  Moving backwards through the array  <--
        // ["0", "0", "0", "0", ... , "0", "5", "X" ]
        for(let i = id_len - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            const next = incrementer[counter[i]]
            if (next) {
                counter[i] = next
                return
            } else {
                counter[i] = min_val
                // No return, it's a carry. Increment the next index.
            }                
        }
    }
    
    return function gen() {
        increment()
        return counter.join("")
    }
}
```

Used like:

```js
const generator = GetGenerator("0000000000005X")

generator()
>>> "0000000000005Y"
generator()
>>> "0000000000005Z"
generator()
>>> "00000000000060"
```